# Client Authentication Certificate error on Android after installing SSL certificate

Tags: android, ssl-certificate-errors

I've recently installed an SSL certificate for my website fantasyfeeder.com.  This appears to be installed correctly when I use the online checker at ssllabs.com (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=fantasyfeeder.com).  The certificate also works fine in desktop browsers and Apple devices.  The problem I have is when testing it on Android (in this case a Samsung Galaxy S4) on both the default Samsung browser and in Chrome.  When I view the website using Wifi it works fine, but when I view it over the mobile network it gives the following error:

SSL Connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server.  This may be a problem with the server or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I can't work out why this error only occurs on Android and only when using the mobile network.

Comment: I've discovered that the second error (You need to set a lock screen pin and password...) is not related.  This was a separate issue caused by a chat application running on a particular page of the website.  For interest, the node.js server application had the option requestCert: true when creating HTTPS connections.  Deleting this option solved the browser error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little NSFW warning would have been nice :D

Anyway, your certificate and web server seems to be correct and should work with any browser supporting SNI (anything above Android 2.x). 
I believe that this is actually problem with the mobile provider of the phone (more so if it works via wifi). From this phone via mobile network are you able accesses https://google.com furthermore you can try other NSFW sites since some counties are keen on filtering those and might be terminating or trying to tamper with the SSL connection.

Comment: Oops, apologies for the lack of NSFW warning!  Yes I can access other websites via HTTPS (including https://google.com) on the mobile device.

Comment: Oops, apologies for the lack of NSFW warning!  Yes I can access other websites via HTTPS (including https://google.com) on the mobile device.  When accessing other NSFW websites via HTTP I get redirected to the mobile network 'Controlled Content' page.  When accessing the same websites via HTTPS I get the SSL connection error.  It seems that you may well be right and the mobile network trying to filter out adult content (albeit not very gracefully for HTTPS requests).  I'll contact them to try and get the adult content filter removed and see if this works.

Comment: Yup, removing the adult filter resolved the problem.  It seems that for HTTPS websites that are content filtered Vodafone displays the confusing 'SSL Connection error' instead of the 'Controlled Content' message.